# Text disappears on refresh

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

When I run the following code, the req.responseText appears quickly in the div #ajax_msg. When the page refreshes (caused by the location.reload), the div #ajax_msg becomes empty.

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function jsUpdateCart(){
   var parameter_string = '';

   allNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("process");

   for (i = 0; i < allNodes.length; i++) {
       var tempid = allNodes[i].id;
       var temp = new Array;
       temp = tempid.split("_");
       var real_id = temp[2];
       var real_value = allNodes[i].value;
       parameter_string += real_id +':'+real_value+',';
   }

   var params = 'ids=' + parameter_string;
   var ajax = new Ajax.Updater(
           'ajax_msg', '/welcome/ajax_cart',
            {method:'post', parameters:params, onComplete:showMessage}
    );     
}



function showMessage(req){
     $('ajax_msg').innerHTML = req.responseText;
     location.reload(true);
}
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Stijn

Comment: why you  use  location.reload(true) ?
as far as i know Ajax is used for dynamic page manipulation ie simply to prevent hulk like Page Refresh !
as per   w3schools 
By default, the reload() method reloads from the cache, but by you can force the the reload to get the page from server by setting the forceGet parameter to true.
location.reload(forceGet)

you are doing the same by   location.reload(true); in showMessage(req)

Comment: If you are wanting to reload the page, then send the data as a form, and just post to the same page.  It sounds like the page is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.  You may need to explain a little better what you are trying to do, or the logic of your operation.

Comment: You should not define variables inside of a `for` loop. Also `i` is not defined. You should hoist all `var`s up to the top of the function.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve here, but if you are concerned that visitors won't be able to see the message, wrap the `reload` inside `setTimeout`.